# How can I automate a cells value changing in Google Sheets to change when the next sheet is altered?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm fed up of the misses complaining that I don't do enough around the house so I've decided to create a cleaning rota that fairly splits the chores. In order to keep on top of who does what chore each week I want the cells to automatically change once the next spreadsheet is edited. For example the check boxes will need to be unchecked and the person completing the chore will swop (one person does it one week then the other does it the week after).

Here's my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JOf383hTLH8Y3fmXCEdPCgKCfwDLBJabfXkP6MnIMkQ/edit?usp=sharing

I know that I will likely have to use some form of script but I need direction into how to do this and what script I would use.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `In order to keep on top of who does what chore each week I want the cells to automatically change once the next spreadsheet is edited. For example the check boxes will need to be unchecked and the person completing the chore will swop (one person does it one week then the other does it the week after).`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: So you want the check mark to walk along the schedule to highlight who's turn it is?  More importantly, do you think the misses will go along with it?

Comment: Sorry guys, let me be a little clearer. I'm going to reuse this sheet. This means that after week 1 has been completed the names need to switch around so the other person does that job when it comes to week 1 again. I also need all of the check boxes to refresh to false when the week has been completed, ready for week 3 ending.

Comment: Could you describe the exact process? 1. User checks a task in Week #1. What needs to happen? 2. User checks a task in Week #2. What needs to happen? As far as I can see, the names are already swapped from week to week. So, the only thing that would have to be done is to uncheck all checkboxes from the previous week?

Comment: The process will be as follows. 1) the user(s) ticks off completed tasks for that day. 2) Once a week is over, the user(s) selects the next week e.g week 2. 3) The user(s) then complete that week. 4) The process is completed through to the end of week 4. 5) The user(s) select week one and repeat the above process again.

Comment: Due to the workload being labour heavy on a particular person each day or chores only being assigned to a certain person, I want the form to switch all names at the end of week 4. E.g all chores assigned to Shaun will now be assigned to Lucy for the following month. I also need all of the Checkboxes to be set to false so that they can be clicked again in the following month.